# How can I align my radio checkboxes so that they are on the left and align the list with other elements on my FCC Survey form?

Tags: html, css

Im attempting freecodecamp's survey-form challenge and I can't seem to get my radio button list to line up with the other elements on the page, how can I fix this?

I'm sure there are plenty bugs in the code but I'd really appreciate some help, thank you in advance!

Html:

```css
.lists{
  grid-template-columns; repeat(2, minmax(50px, 1fr));
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 10px 5px 5px;
  text-align: right; 
  max-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="lists">
   <ul> 
    <li><label> Women-only Classes<input name="improvements" type="checkbox"value="1"></label></li>
    <li><label>More free-weights<input name="improvements" type="checkbox" value="2"> </label></li>
    <li><label>24 hour access<input name="improvements" type="checkbox" value="3"></label></li>
    <li><label>Late night classes<input name="improvements" type="checkbox" value="4"></label></li>
    <li><label>On-site health checks<input name="improvements" type="checkbox" value="5"> </label></li>  
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: if you can in your html structure than add input box before text...

Answer (score 0):

You can used `position: absolute`:

```css
.lists{
  grid-template-columns; repeat(2, minmax(50px, 1fr));
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 10px 5px 5px;
  text-align: right; 
  max-width: 300px;
}

.lists li label {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.lists input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="lists">
   <ul> 
    <li><label> Women-only Classes<input name="improvements" type="checkbox"value="1"></label></li>
    <li><label>More free-weights<input name="improvements" type="checkbox" value="2"> </label></li>
    <li><label>24 hour access<input name="improvements" type="checkbox" value="3"></label></li>
    <li><label>Late night classes<input name="improvements" type="checkbox" value="4"></label></li>
    <li><label>On-site health checks<input name="improvements" type="checkbox" value="5"> </label></li>  
  </ul>
</div>
```